# Populate a dropdownlist from stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a method `Edit` where I send an `id` to a `stored procedure` and I get back the data from a db table. I am trying to populate several dropdown lists with the data I am getting back from the stored procedure but it's not working, the values in my dropdowns are empty.

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            string conString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("nobp_LoadSettlementContract", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OBJECTID", id);
            
            Model results = new Model();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Model cs = new Model ();
                        cs.TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID = dr.GetString(0);
                        cs.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID = dr.GetString(1);
                        cs.CustomerType = dr.GetString(2);
                        results = cs;
                    }
                }
        
            
            ViewBag.Technology = new SelectList(results.Technology);
            ViewBag.DownloadSpeed = new SelectList(results.DownloadSpeed);
            ViewBag.CustomerType = new SelectList(results.CustomerType);
            return View(results);

}
```

This is my view

```
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Technology, ViewBag.Technology as SelectList, "please choose", new { @name = "Technology", @id = "TechnologyID", @class = "form-control chosen", required = "required" })
            </div>
```

I also tried something like this

```
ViewBag.Technology = new SelectList(results.Technology, "TECHNOLOGY_DESCRIPTION");
```

but I can't get it to work. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: debug it, and inspect the runtime values. code looks good at first glance. are the dropdowns filled with items which are empty strings, or are the entirely empty (no items)?

Comment: there is `results`, which is a single instance of `Model` and which is reassigned inside the loop. you'll want to add an entry with each loop iteration, instead of setting the same value again. or is this just about setting the value of one record, in this case the dropdowns would have been populated already, and you're only going to select a value in each?

Comment: so, english isn't my native language so bear with me while I try to fully understand you. 
I am trying to get the record from db, which the stored procedure returns correctly and trying to populate these dropdowns with the values from the database. 
So, for example I `Save` a record in db with `Viewbag.Technology = 1` and so on for the other dropdowns but when I try to edit the same record, the dropdowns are empty. No value is selected.